# Arch Linux error on boot: "fsck: /sbin/fsck.ext4: execute failed: Exec format error"

Tags: arch-linux, fsck

I am not sure what this is or how to fix it. This error displays on boot and shortly afterwards everything appears to freeze just before my display manager is loaded.

I have also tried chroot'ing and running 'fsck -a', but similar error results are printed to the screen.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.24.2
fsck: /sbin/fsck.ext4: execute failed: Exec format error
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*Exec format error*'s are often difficult to diagnose, because they may refer to things like a missing she-bang in a shell script, an empty line before the she-bang in a perl script, and so on.

Since however you are trying to run an executable (fsck.ext4 is just a symlink back to e2fsck), the most likely cause of error is that you are mixing architectures: in other words, you may have code for a 64bit system when you are really running a 32bit system, or vice versa.

This is not a unique diagnosis of this problem, it is however a common one.